# How to insert IDs into the barcharts in R

Tags: r, ggplot2

Here is a hypothetical samp;e of my data :

```html
dd<-read.table (text=" ID   Group
1   A
2   C
4   A
9   B
6   A
8   B
12  A
5   C

", header=TRUE)
```

I want to insert IDs inside the bars for each group. This will give me the following plot.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `ggplot2` and a bit of `dplyr` for the data wrangling you could achieve your desired result like so:

**EDIT** Added `ggtext::geom_textbox` for automatic line breaks.

```
set.seed(123)

dd <- data.frame(
  Group = sample(LETTERS[1:3], 100, replace = TRUE),
  ID = 1:100
)

library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)

dd <- dd %>%
  group_by(Group) |>
  summarise(n = n(), label = paste(ID, collapse = ", "))

pal_fill <- c("#90EE90", "#FFFF00", "#F0E68C")

ggplot(dd, aes(Group, n, fill = Group)) +
  geom_col(color = "black") +
  geom_text(aes(label = n), vjust = 0, nudge_y = 1) +
  ggtext::geom_textbox(aes(label = label),
    vjust = 1, nudge_y = -1,
    hjust = .5, nudge_x = 0, box.color = NA,
    maxwidth = .45
  ) +
  scale_fill_manual(values = pal_fill) +
  scale_y_continuous(expand = c(0, 0, .05, 0)) +
  theme_bw() +
  theme(
    panel.border = element_blank(), panel.grid = element_blank(),
    axis.line.y = element_line(), axis.ticks.x = element_blank(),
    axis.ticks.length.y = unit(5, "pt")
  ) +
  labs(x = NULL, y = NULL) +
  guides(fill = "none")
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you. The issue is that when you have many IDs, say 100, they will not be inserted in the bar but placed outside the bar. Can we solve this issue?

Comment: Sure are there options. I just made an edit which uses `ggtext::geom_textbox` for automatic line breaks. Depending on the outputted size of your plot you have to play a bit around with e.g. the `maxwidth` argument.

Comment: Do you get the error when you run my code or do you get the error if you run the code on your data?

Comment: Apologetically,  I made mistake- Many thanks for your help and upvoted